# Two-way encryption for public hash in redirect links in PHP

Tags: php, redirect, encryption, public-key-encryption

I have the database with news. Each news contains external url. I have such redirect links on my site to redirect to news links:

```
__http://example.com/jump?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsome-external-site.com%2Fsome-page.html
```

Such links are visible to all (to users and search engines). I need to replace value of `url` to some kind of hash which I could decrypt on my server and redirect users to that encrypted url. So I want my redirect urls looks like this:

```
__http://example.com/jump?url=U5jYu71UVxtojRBUqPPlkjop7xMJ7AWLnXhJ1HK6VSNFmS522p4aDGVy54VAE
```

After decryption of `U5jYu71UVxtojRBUqPPlkjop7xMJ7AWLnXhJ1HK6VSNFmS522p4aDGVy54VAE` it should looks like this:

```
_https://some-external-site.com/some-page.html
```

I tried `openssl_encrypt` from example at php docs ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php ):

```
<?php
//$key should have been previously generated in a cryptographically safe way, like openssl_random_pseudo_bytes
$plaintext = "message to be encrypted";
$cipher = "aes-128-gcm";
if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
{
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
    //store $cipher, $iv, and $tag for decryption later
    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
    echo $original_plaintext."\n";
}
?>
```

but it looks like it generates all time different encrypted string.

What options do I have? How does popular sites do this? They also use redirect links with hashed external urls.

Comment: if you generate and store a unique hash for each url ( in the same table ) you can do a database lookup on the requested url to process that hash - if the hash exists in the db then redirect the user to the relevant url - if not flag as an error?

Comment: @RamRaider, yes, it is a good idea. But I also use such redirect urls in blogs where users can add content with links. It will be easier for me just use two-way encryption instead of checking hash imprint (md5, sha1, etc).

Comment: just be cautious of allowing users to add links that, when click, originate from your site as they can possibly craft malicious links in an effort to probe their intended target site and all the requests would appear to originate from your site

Comment: @RamRaider, users already do it. Someone generate redirect links using my domain as part of the link and use that links for their malicious goals and I have got abuses to my site. I mean they didn't add malicious urls on my site but use it somewhere else. That is why I want to use hashes instead of urlencoded strings within `url` parameter of redirect link. My goal is to prevent someone to generate his own redirect links pointed to my site.

Comment: @RamRaider, do you have some idea how is this done at news.google.com? They use urls like this __https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEH-m0etvJ2rDP6OGR238ceAqFAgEKg0IACoGCAowlIEBMLEXMOc_?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen . Does google use two-way encrtyprion or only check hash imprint?

Comment: No - I don't know for sure. If it were encrypted at runtime it would change so they probably create a hash of some sort for that story which is used to retrieve the real url. Using complex urls like this prevent automated trawling to a degree as you can't simply try incremental ids to retrieve content.. Only Google know how they do what they do...

Comment: "it looks like it generates all time different encrypted string". It's supposed to do this. It happens because the IV is different every time, [as it should be](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26790/how-bad-it-is-using-the-same-iv-twice-with-aes-gcm). Why is this a problem?

Comment: @Peter, I was looking for some kind of encryption algorithm with which I could encrypt  url with some kind of private key (one for all urls) and decrypt string back to url. I was interesting how google (  `_https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEH-m0etvJ2rDP6OGR238ceAqFAgEKg0IACoGCAowlIEBMLEXMOc?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen `) and facebook do this for redirection urls (facebook uses such links `_https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fsome-domain.com/some-page.html ?h=gkTMTNd8XaP...b1n87l_gMXc...nX3fR3FqldBuw...2uzCSpq2TEoH...PCvIwKSRnLx...m1WLsfxH...7GluA51BZST...KnvLMbC` ).

Comment: @Peter, I want to do it in google or facebook style. Google uses only hash in redirect urs but I don't know if that hash they can decrypt or uses it only for checking imprint. Facebook uses redirect url with hash (`h` parameter in url) and I am interesting if they can decrypt it or is this only hash imprint too?